# html - How are pixels defined?

Tags: html, css, pixel, definition

From my experience up to now the pixel size is something very relevant and intepreted differently based on many factors. My question is how do pixels work in html pages.

For example we can set the width and height of an image:

```
<img src="lalala.jpg" width="100px;" height="100px;">
```

What does 100 pixels actually mean?
How are the 100 pixels translated on screen? 
How are the 100 pixels translated if on print papper?

To be more specific. If I set the image size to 100px then is it going to be the same size in inches on  different screen sizes ? Ad if so..Is it going to be the same size if I print the same page while using a different screen size?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

Comment: Wait. `width` and `height` attributes do not have unit.

Comment: @Raptor Yes they do.

Comment: @Mr.E Not in HTML they don't.

Answer (score 5):

In HTML, pixel lengths of the `height` and `width` attributes are controlled by CSS. In some instances, these are refereed to as *"CSS pixels"*. HTML itself does not provide a definition for what a pixel should represent (thus why I added the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag into your question).

CSS itself has its own [Units and Values documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) which defines the Pixel in its section on [Absolute Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths):

> ### 5.2. Absolute lengths: the ‘cm’, ‘mm’, ‘in’, ‘pt’, ‘pc’, ‘px’ units
>
> The absolute length units are fixed in relation to each other and anchored to some physical measurement. They are mainly useful when the output environment is known. The absolute units consist of the physical units (in, cm, mm, pt, pc) and the px unit:
>
> ```
> unit    definition
> ----    ----------
> ‘cm’    centimeters
> ‘mm’    millimeters
> ‘in’    inches; 1in is equal to 2.54cm
> ‘px’    pixels; 1px is equal to 1/96th of 1in
> ‘pt’    points; 1pt is equal to 1/72nd of 1in
> ‘pc’    picas; 1pc is equal to 12pt
> ```

100 pixels is equal to roughly 1.041in, which itself is equal to roughly 2.65cm.

I'm not going to answer the further questions you've asked about different monitors and printing as this would make my answer incredibly long and dull. If you want to find out these answers yourself, a good place to start is in the same document I've already linked, which goes into detail about the [Reference Pixel](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#reference-pixel). Values in CSS are based upon a value of 96dpi (which means that 96 pixels on a monitor which has a pixel dencity of 96dpi will be equal to one inch if you were to measure it with a ruler).

Comment: @Raptor no I didn't. `em` is a ["font-relative unit"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths) and not an "absolute length".

Comment: got it. I overlook Absolute part

Comment: @Flynn1179 that implies that your monitor has a pixel density greater than 96dpi.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you for the information! I wonder how big a picture should be? I know how big it should be on the screen, but not how big the image should be, as an example. I know I want a width of 400px. If the pictures have 400px in width, I can count them on the screen. Can you help me there?

Answer (score 0):

Because every screen has diferent pixel size HTML/CSS or whatever software language is going to be made never gonna match the physical pixel size.
To calculate pixel size you need Hardware machine language not software.